# Nesting angularjs directives recursively

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having a problem in my application where I would like to have a directive, and inside its template it should conditionally decide whether to recursively render that same directive within it. I have tried to recreate it, and this example is also not working. The directive is not rendered and without errors. I could have made a different mistake in it however.

https://plnkr.co/edit/PhDvLZyWvyFThg57qZDV?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
          <span ng-bind="menu.Text"></span>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li menu-entry menus="menu.SubMenus"></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

**menu-entry.html**

```
<li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
    <a ng-if="menu.Submenus.length===0" ng-bind="menu.Text"></a>
    <button ng-if="menu.Submenus.length>0" type="button" ng-bind="menu.Text">
        <span class="caret caret-right"></span>
    </button>
    <ul ng-if="menu.Submenus.length>0" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li menu-entry menus="menu.SubMenus"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.menus = [
    { Text: '1', SubMenus: [
      { Text: '1.1', SubMenus: [{Text:'1.1.1',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'1.1.2',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'1.1.3',SubMenus:[]}]},
      { Text: '1.2', SubMenus: [{Text:'1.2.1',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'1.2.2',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'1.2.3',SubMenus:[]}]},
      { Text: '1.3', SubMenus: [{Text:'1.3.1',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'1.3.2',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'1.3.3',SubMenus:[]}]}
      ]},
    { Text: '2', SubMenus: [
    { Text: '2.1', SubMenus: [{Text:'2.1.1',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'2.1.2',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'2.1.3',SubMenus:[]}]},
    { Text: '2.2', SubMenus: [{Text:'2.2.1',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'2.2.2',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'2.2.3',SubMenus:[]}]},
    { Text: '2.3', SubMenus: [{Text:'2.3.1',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'2.3.2',SubMenus:[]},{Text:'2.3.3',SubMenus:[]}]}
    ]},
    ];
});

app.directive('menuEntry', function() {
        var cFn = ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        }];

        var lFn = function (scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
        };

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'menu-entry.html',
            controller: cFn,
            link: lFn,
            scope: {
                menus: '='
            }
        };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are 3 problems with your current directive implementation.

- The problem is you had directive on `li` element with `replace: true` which is adding one template which has `ul` again. So resultant html was incorrect in format, as you can not have `ul` inside `ul` again. **Change you directive `replace: true` to `replace: false` **OR** just remove that option.**
- There on your directive template `menu.Submenus` should be `menu.SubMenus`

**Template**

```
<li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
  {{menu.Text}}
    <a ng-if="menu.SubMenus.length == 0" ng-bind="menu.Text"></a>
    <button ng-if="menu.Submenus.length>0" type="button" ng-bind="menu.Text">
        <span class="caret caret-right"></span>
    </button>
    <ul ng-if="menu.SubMenus.length>0" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li menu-entry menus="menu.SubMenus"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NicMpRqD8W1G7Van5Srs?p=preview)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. The recursive menus aren't rendered however. There are no 1.1.1, 1.2.1, 1.3.1, etc

Comment: Much appreciated. I now need to see if I can figure out what was wrong in my actual program, as I can now see that since updating to `SubMenus` it is working at least. `length` was correct in my original code, and `replace:true` works, otherwise you have an li inside an li

Comment: Maybe not important, but in case someone else looks at this. You should maybe remove the `lenght` part from your answer as that wasn't inside my code that I posted. Also the `replace:true` part is correct as it wouldn't be a ul inside a ul. It would replace the li with the li inside it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a typo:
Submenus -> SubMenus

You defined in script.js objects with SubMenus, but you refer in your template to Submenus.